# Could not find devise mapping for path

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have the following routes defined in my routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "network/registrations",sessions: 'network/sessions', passwords: 'network/passwords' }


devise_scope :user do
   get "registrations/show" => "network/registrations", as: :show_user_profile
end
```

and when i do rake routes i also see

```
 network_show_user_profile GET    /network/registrations/show(.:format)                                                                network/registrations#show
```

But when i try to access the path /network/registrations/show

i get the below exception

Could not find devise mapping for path "/network/registrations/show".
This may happen for two reasons:

```
1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:

  devise_scope :user do
    get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
  end

2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
   If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:

   @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

I tried to modify the routes.rb and added

```
devise_scope :user do
  get 'user_profile' => 'registrations#search', :as => 'user_profile'
end
```

and when i access user_profile path, i get the error

```
The action 'show' could not be found for Network::RegistrationsController
```

**but when i add the action show to the controller I again get the same exception message**

Could not find devise mapping for path "/network/registrations/show".
This may happen for two reasons:

```
1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:

  devise_scope :user do
    get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
  end

2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
   If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:

   @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

any help as to what i am doing wrong would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding same routes that you did

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "network/registrations",sessions: 'network/sessions', passwords: 'network/passwords' }


  devise_scope :user do
     get "registrations/show" => "network/registrations", as: :show_user_profile
  end
end
```

But instead of

`network_show_user_profile GET    /network/registrations/show(.:format)`

I got `show_user_profile GET    /registrations/show(.:format)     registrations#show`

So I replaced this routes file with below

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "network/registrations",sessions: 'network/sessions', passwords: 'network/passwords' }


  devise_scope :user do
     get "/network/registrations/show" => "network/registrations#show", as: :show_user_profile
  end
end
```

I also created an action `show` in `network/registrations_controller.rb` and

everything works perfectly for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @nimish that again for your reply. But it still is giving me same error, not sure what mistake i am doing

Comment: please share your route.rb and complete error trace

Comment: Hi Nimish, i have made a update to the question. Can you please check if that helps in anyway.

Comment: Nimish i have created a simple rails application to debug this and soon as i use namespaces for routes the issue arise.

Comment: Have you found out the solution?